Shape mismatch between the output of generator and input expected by discriminator
The main issue that I faced was that the discriminator model is expecting an input shape of (None, 14336) for the dense layer, but it turned out to be receiving the input shape of (None, 53760).
I tried tweaking the model architecture by reshaping the output of the dense layer in build generator before applying the convolutional transpose layers. I was expecting the shape for the dense layer output to match the input size of the first convolutional layer in the discriminator.
# generator model
def build_generator(z_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=z_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    model.add(Dense(29 * 27 * 128))  
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    model.add(Reshape((29, 27, 128)))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same", activation='tanh'))
    model.summary()  

    # Print shapes after each layer
    for layer in model.layers:
        print(layer.output_shape)

    return model

# discriminator model
def build_discriminator(img_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same", input_shape=img_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    print(model.output_shape)  
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    print(model.output_shape) 
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
    print(model.output_shape)  
    model.add(Flatten())
    print(model.output_shape)  
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.summary()
    return model

# gradient penalty
def gradient_penalty_loss(y_true, y_pred, averaged_samples):
    gradients = tf.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
    gradients_sqr = tf.square(gradients)
    gradients_sqr_sum = tf.reduce_sum(gradients_sqr, axis=np.arange(1, len(gradients_sqr.shape)))
    gradient_l2_norm = tf.sqrt(gradients_sqr_sum)
    gradient_penalty = tf.square(1 - gradient_l2_norm)
    return tf.reduce_mean(gradient_penalty)

#  WGAN-GP loss
def wasserstein_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -tf.reduce_mean(y_true * y_pred)

def build_gan(generator, discriminator, z_dim):
    discriminator.trainable = False
    z = Input(shape=(z_dim,))
    img = generator(z)
    validity = discriminator(img)
    combined = Model(z, validity)
    combined.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=Adam())
    return combined

img_shape = (58, 54, 4)
z_dim = 100

discriminator = build_discriminator(img_shape)
discriminator.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=Adam(clipvalue=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

generator = build_generator(z_dim)


z = Input(shape=(z_dim,))
img = generator(z)
print("Shape of input data to the discriminator:", img.shape)  
gan = build_gan(generator, discriminator, z_dim)

The output that it returned:
(None, 29, 27, 64)
(None, 15, 14, 128)
(None, 8, 7, 256)
(None, 14336)
Model: "sequential_69"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_575 (Conv2D)         (None, 29, 27, 64)        4160      
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_206 (LeakyReLU  (None, 29, 27, 64)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_576 (Conv2D)         (None, 15, 14, 128)       131200    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_207 (LeakyReLU  (None, 15, 14, 128)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_577 (Conv2D)         (None, 8, 7, 256)         524544    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_208 (LeakyReLU  (None, 8, 7, 256)         0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 flatten_35 (Flatten)        (None, 14336)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_85 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 14337     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 674241 (2.57 MB)
Trainable params: 674241 (2.57 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_70"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_86 (Dense)            (None, 256)               25856     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_209 (LeakyReLU  (None, 256)               0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 dense_87 (Dense)            (None, 100224)            25757568  
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_210 (LeakyReLU  (None, 100224)            0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 reshape_33 (Reshape)        (None, 29, 27, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_85 (Conv2  (None, 58, 54, 64)        131136    
 DTranspose)                                                     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_211 (LeakyReLU  (None, 58, 54, 64)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_86 (Conv2  (None, 116, 108, 4)       4100      
 DTranspose)                                                     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 25918660 (98.87 MB)
Trainable params: 25918660 (98.87 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
(None, 256)
(None, 256)
(None, 100224)
(None, 100224)
(None, 29, 27, 128)
(None, 58, 54, 64)
(None, 58, 54, 64)
(None, 116, 108, 4)
Shape of input data to the discriminator: (None, 116, 108, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-ccbd9e7f0e21> in <cell line: 77>()
     75 img = generator(z)
     76 print("Shape of input data to the discriminator:", img.shape)  # Add this line to debug
---> 77 gan = build_gan(generator, discriminator, z_dim)

2 frames
<ipython-input-42-ccbd9e7f0e21> in build_gan(generator, discriminator, z_dim)
     54     z = Input(shape=(z_dim,))
     55     img = generator(z)
---> 56     validity = discriminator(img)
     57     combined = Model(z, validity)
     58     combined.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=Adam())

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    278                     None,
    279                 }:
--> 280                     raise ValueError(
    281                         f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '
    282                         f"incompatible with the layer: expected axis {axis} "

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_69" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense_85" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 14336, but received input with shape (None, 53760)

Call arguments received by layer "sequential_69" (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 116, 108, 4), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None


I am at my wits end, not knowing how to make the necessary changes. Could someone pinpoint my mistake?
Thanks for reading my post.
